# const std::string::size() is much larger than it should be in optimization level 2

Tags: c++11, compilation, stdstring

Definition:

```cpp
const std::string a_class::dft_col_name{"NONE"};
```

Usage:

in a_class::function()

just loop one time, i is 0

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < result->colnum; ++i) {
    result->pcolname[(i + 1) * SQLCOLLEN - 1] = '\0';
    auto colname_len = strlen(result->pcolname + i * SQLCOLLEN);
    if (colname_len == 0) {
        // given column name if there isn't
        strcpy(result->pcolname + i * SQLCOLLEN, dft_col_name.c_str());
        colname_len = dft_col_name.size();

        /*!! Confusion !!*/

        std::cout << dft_col_name << '\n';
        // O2 print: lots of corrupted text
        std::cout << dft_col_name.c_str() << '\n';
        // O2 print: "NONE"
        printf("%lu %lu %s\n", colname_len, dft_col_name.size(), dft_col_name.c_str());
        // -g O0 print: 4 4 NONE
        // O2 print: 17179869184 17179869184 NONE

    }
    result->plen[i] = colname_len;
}
```

Some debug information copied as:

```bash
66                  std::cout << dft_col_name.size() << '\n';
(gdb) 
17179869184
67                  colname_len = dft_col_name.size();
(gdb) p dft_col_name 
$1 = ""
(gdb) p dft_col_name .size()
$2 = 4
(gdb) p dft_col_name.c_str()
$3 = 0x659c98 "NONE"
```

What is `result`:

```cpp
struct ResultInfo{
...
int16_t colnum; // SQL result column number. It's 1 in this problem.
...
int16_t* pcolname; // SQL result columns' name. Each has SQLCOLEN characters.
...
};

#define SQLCOLEN 64
```

It's deserialized from net and in memory it looks like:

```
| struct ResultInfo | <pcolname point to here> colnum * 64 char |
```

Environment:

```
Linux version 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org)
(gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Feb 4 23:02:59 UTC 2020

g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm really confused about it!

I tried using `valgrind --tool=memcheck` to debug, and no `Invalid write` was found.

I tried relacing `const std::string` to `const char[]`, `dft_col_name.size()` to `strlen()`, and it worked.

I tried removing `static const std::string a_class::dft_col_name` from  class member to `const std::string dft_col_name` as a global variable  in `.cpp`, or a local variable in `a_class::function()`. It didn't work.

Comment: I compile it in optimization level 1 with `-g` option, then `gdb` it.  Variable `dft_col_name` is `value has been optimized out`

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]? Understanding what `result` and `SQLCOLLEN` are would help. It certainly looks like you're corrupting memory somewhere.

Comment: Another common problem: Using `a_class::function()` during initialization of a global static object where it isn't guaranteed yet that `a_class::dft_col_name`'s initialization finished.

Comment: It's hard to provide a minimal reproducible example because it's a complex system. I add description of `result` above.

Comment: `a_class::dft_col_name` initializes at program begining, then I input SQL, then `a_class` object constructs, then `a_class::function()` called. So I think `a_class::function()` is called after `a_class::dft_col_name`'s initialization .

Comment: You are writing out-of-bounds somewhere. Instead of valgrind you can also try ASAN to detect it. I don't think more can be said with the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more time to solve this problem. Relacing `const std::string` to `const char[]` works temporarily.

After days hard work, we found that there is `#pragma pack(push, 1)` in one of headers, but not a `#pragma pack(pop)`!!!